# list of unique elements from textstat_simil with loop

Tags: corpus, quanteda

This is a followup question from a response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626262/how-to-compute-similarity-in-quanteda-between-documents-for-adjacent-years-only).

Below, I can generate jaccard similarity for adjacent pairs (1993 then 1994). How can I use as.list() to return a list of unique items for each comparison? Here's what I'm working with:

library("quanteda")

```
data_corpus_inaugural$president <- paste(data_corpus_inaugural$President,
  data_corpus_inaugural$FirstName,
  sep = ", "
)

head(data_corpus_inaugural$president, 10)
##  [1] "Washington, George" "Washington, George" "Adams, John"       
##  [4] "Jefferson, Thomas"  "Jefferson, Thomas"  "Madison, James"    
##  [7] "Madison, James"     "Monroe, James"      "Monroe, James"     
## [10] "Adams, John Quincy"


simpairs <- lapply(unique(data_corpus_inaugural$president), function(x) {
  dfmat <- corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, president == x) %>%
    dfm(remove_punct = TRUE)
  df <- data.frame()
  years <- sort(dfmat$Year)
  for (i in seq_along(years)[-length(years)]) {
    sim <- textstat_simil(
      dfm_subset(dfmat, Year %in% c(years[i], years[i + 1])),
      method = "jaccard"
    )
    df <- rbind(df, as.data.frame(sim))
  }
  df
})

do.call(rbind, simpairs)

##          document1       document2    jaccard
## 1  1789-Washington 1793-Washington 0.09250399
## 2   1801-Jefferson  1805-Jefferson 0.20512821
## 3     1809-Madison    1813-Madison 0.20138889
## 4      1817-Monroe     1821-Monroe 0.29436202
## 5     1829-Jackson    1833-Jackson 0.20693928
## 6     1861-Lincoln    1865-Lincoln 0.14055885
## 7       1869-Grant      1873-Grant 0.20981595
## 8   1885-Cleveland  1893-Cleveland 0.23037543
## 9    1897-McKinley   1901-McKinley 0.25031211
## 10     1913-Wilson     1917-Wilson 0.21285564
## 11  1933-Roosevelt  1937-Roosevelt 0.20956522
## 12  1937-Roosevelt  1941-Roosevelt 0.20081549
## 13  1941-Roosevelt  1945-Roosevelt 0.18740157
## 14 1953-Eisenhower 1957-Eisenhower 0.21566976
## 15      1969-Nixon      1973-Nixon 0.23451777
## 16     1981-Reagan     1985-Reagan 0.24381368
## 17    1993-Clinton    1997-Clinton 0.24199623
## 18       2001-Bush       2005-Bush 0.24170616
## 19      2009-Obama      2013-Obama 0.24739195
```

So, for example, how would I retrieve the items in 1789-Washington that are not in 1793-Washington, and vice versa? ... And retrieve unique items for each pair of adjacent texts?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output that you want?

Comment: Yes. Here the general idea.  Text A is "red, green, blue, purple" and Text B is "blue, purple, yellow, and pink". I would like output to be (a) "red, green, blue" and (b) "yellow and pink". That may require two different procedures generating two different lists or data frames.

Comment: Your output compares documents, but the output you suggest in the comment above is for feature similarities. I suggest you revise the question to clearly state what you are seeking, since your comment seems very unconnected to the included example.

Comment: Will do. My shortcoming here is not understanding the distinction between comparing tokens and texts. My analysis is comparing tokens of one text and tokens of another. There is a set that exists in Text A only, a set that exists in Text B only, and a set that is shared between the two--which is what I had understood jaccard similarity to quantify. I wanted the set of unique tokens in each text and then to do this for over 2000 short texts.

Comment: If you want a list of tokens that are unique to A, unique to B, and shared, that's actually easy and does not require textstat_simil. I can answer that if you revise the question with a simple example of what you just described.