# How to use a custom tokenizer in quanteda pipeline

Tags: r, quanteda

I would like to use a custom tokenizer based on the `tokenizers` page within the quanteda pipeline `df %>% corpus() %>% tokens() %>% dfm()`.

But I can't get it going...

An example:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:3), text = c("my first text string", "and another one", "huch, just another"))

  id                 text
1  1 my first text string
2  2      and another one
3  3   huch, just another
```

Of course I looked up how I can use the `quanteda` tokenizer in combination with `tokenizers`:

```
tokens(tokenizers::tokenize_sentences(df$text))
Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
text1 :
[1] "my first text string"

text2 :
[1] "and another one"

text3 :
[1] "huch, just another"
```

But I would like to use this with a `corpus()` object to keep data on IDs.

The obvious thing does not work:

```
df %>% corpus() %>% tokens(tokenizers::tokenize_sentences(.)) %>% dfm()

 Error in match.arg(what, c("word", "word1", "sentence", "character", "fasterword",  : 
      'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

I guess, it's because pipeing into `tokenizers` doesn't yield a result:

```
df$text %>% tokens(tokenizers::tokenize_sentences(.))

Error in match.arg(what, c("word", "word1", "sentence", "character", "fasterword",  : 
  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

What's a workaround?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The method below won't work if your documents actually consisted of more than one sentence. What output do you want to achieve? There are several ways to do this. Any list can be converted to a tokens object using `as.tokens()`, not `tokens()`. The output from `tokenisers::tokenize_sentences()` is a list. I can demonstrate the method if you clarify what result you seek.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! 

My ultimate goal is to use quanteda for deduplication. To do that, I want to use two-character shingles that were sorted alphabetically before slicing them. Then strings like "Eve Myers Publisher" and "Publisher Eve Myers" are going to have a cosine similiarity = 1.

The strings that should be compared are stored in two columns, so the computation is rowwise. But that's another topic.

Comment: basically I would like to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240511/list-of-unique-elements-from-textstat-simil-with-loop but with custom tokens